# Flask-admin : How to auto update the data in table2 when table1 is edited?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am using flask-admin and displaying a few custom forms using baseView and once the data is entered and submitted it is getting stored in the tables of the database. Now I want it to update the data across all the tables if an edit is made to a table named 1. I tried using on_model_change() function but it still doesn't work. Even after_model_change() functions aren't working. Is there any fix for this ?

This is my tables or models :
table 1:

```
class Test1(db.Model):
    Test_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    Test_name = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=True)
```

table 2:

```
class test_details(db.Model):
    details_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    invoice_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    test_name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    created_by = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),
                             default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoice_id
```

This is my custom view for a form :

```
class testUserView(BaseView):

    def is_accessible(self):
        if not current_user.is_active or not current_user.is_authenticated:
            return False
        if current_user.has_role('superuser') or current_user.has_role('user'):
            return True
        return False
    
    def after_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        print("after_model_change called")
        if is_created:
            print("Hey, new record created with values:")

    @expose('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index(self):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.form
            # print(data)
            generate_id(data)
            return jsonify({'success': True})
        # return self.render('admin/usertest.html')
        speciesData = get_species_table_data()
        specimenData = get_specimen_table_data()
        locationData = get_location_table_data()
        clinicalTestData = get_clinicalTest_table_data()
        clinicalTestDatas = json.dumps(clinicalTestData)
        return self.render('admin/usertest.html', speciesData=speciesData, specimenData=specimenData, locationData=locationData, clinicalTestData=clinicalTestDatas, admin_base_template=admin.base_template)
```

admin added view :

```
admin.add_view(testUserView(name="Create Order",
               endpoint='usertest', category='Manage Orders'))
```

I tried using on_model_change() and after_model_change() functions that act as event handlers for flask-admin. I expected it to print "after_model_change called" but the text is not being displayed on the console meaning the function is not being called. How can I FIX THIS ? PLEASE HELP

Comment: As you are using SqlAlchemy your Flask-Admin views need to inherit from `ModelView`. See [Adding Model Views](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#adding-model-views)

Comment: @pjcunningham I found my mistake, I was supposed to add on_model_change to the table that is experiencing the changes. The model that is inheriting the BaseView has no db session, and hence it wasn't working. Thanks for you advice, Ill mark it as an answer.